# the correct way to input images for testing the tensorflow model

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

I have been trying to test the fcn implementation [posted here](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn/blob/master/test_fcn32_vgg.py). The only thing I changed is the way for setting up the input images for test against the model. My modification is marked with red curve in the following figure.

[image]

However, running the program caused the following error message `TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.`
, happened at `down, up = sess.run(tensors, feed_dict=feed_dict)`. I am curious to know what are something wrong in my implementation, and how to modify it.  In the original post, the author uses `img1 = skimage.io.imread("./test_data/tabby_cat.png")`
  to input the image.

If I change `batch_images=tf.expand_dims(images,0)` to `batch_images=tf.expand_dims(img1,0)`  the program will output the following error messages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, the types of values that you can use as feeds are Python scalars, strings, lists or numpy arrays. What you are trying to use as feed is `img1`, the output of `tf.image.decode_png`, which is of type `tf.Tensor`. Hence the error. You have two options :

1) Convert `img1` to a numpy array before feeding it. You can do that by simply *evaluating* `img1` as follows :

```
feed_dict = {images:img1.eval()}
```

2) Use `img1` itself as the input to the rest of the model. You can do that as follows :

```
batch_images = tf.expand_dims(img1, 0)
```

Comment: Hi, Keveman, thanks for the reply. I tried the first approach previously, but the program just stop at line of  feed_dict = {images:img1.eval()} forever without moving forward or exit with some error messages. It just stopped there.

I just tried the second approach, the result is included in the original one. Looks like model building process does not even go through.

Comment: For the second approach, try `batch_images = tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(img1, tf.float32), 0)`

Comment: Hi keveman, thanks for your suggestion, I tried it, then the error message o f "TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
" appears again.